# Python xlrd module

Tags: python, xlrd

According to the documentation of the XLRD module,

```
 row_values(rowx, start_colx=0, end_colx=None)
```

"Returns a slice of the values of the cells in the given row."

And given the following python code:

```
import xlrd
wb=xlrd.open_workbook("xl1.xlsx")
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
for rownum in range(sh.nrows):
    print sh.row_values(rownum)
```

The output is:

```
 [12.0, u'test.0']
 [34.0, u'te.st']
 [u'test123', u'12.test']
```

and the exel file holds the following data:

12.0   , test.0 , 34.0  ,   te.st  , test123 , 12.test

So, what type of data structure do I get as a line according to the output?
Its not a tuple, (becasue when printing a tuple type, there is no u' as a prefix to a string), and what is the meaning of the u' ? 
And also its like we have two types of data in the data structure - int and "non int".
Is it true? I could not find any information about this in the documentation.
Thanks!

Comment: Strings prefixed with `u` are unicode strings. Just ignore the `u`.

Comment: So each line in the excel file holds only int or string, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`row_values` returns a list of cell values with appropriate data types. Data type of each item in the list depends on the cell type in the source excel file.

There could be items with only `string`, `float` and `int` data types, see this [mapping table](http://www.lexicon.net/sjmachin/xlrd.html#Cell) (find there docs for `Cell`) for more info.

`u` just means that this is a unicode string. [Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#unicode-strings) explains it pretty well.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

First things first!
I don't know which version of xlrd you are using but according to the latest version(xlrd 0.9.4 at the time of writing this answer):

```
row_values()
```

will return you with the values in the row in the form of a list. This can be verified by typing:

```
>>> type(sh.row_values(2))
<type 'list'>
```

Next to get the values of the row including the data types, you can type the following:

```
>>> sh.row(2)
```

Which will return you something like this:

```
[number:12.0, text:u'test.0']
```

Meaning that the first item in the list is a number and the second item is a string or also called as text.

Finally the `u` in front of the string means that it is Unicode encoding. Remember that xlrd module will try to render each and every data in excel sheet to unicode encoding and so you are seeing `u`

[xlrd module official documentation](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html?p=4966#sheet.Sheet.row-method)