# Python Script to search Excel database

Tags: python, excel, logging

Is there a command using python language to search excel database?
Here's the simple excel details of nombor x30.

[image]

Example if wan to search nombor.3 details from excel, then it will display all row details into log file.

Thank you !

Comment: openpyxl is a library for excel IO

Comment: https://www.vitoshacademy.com/how-to-search-in-a-worksheet-with-python/

Comment: Have you done any research? There are plenty of resources on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

## Program to extract a particular row value

```
import xlrd 

loc = ("path of file") 
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc) 
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0) 
sheet.cell_value(0, 0) 
print(sheet.row_values(1))
```

Comment: that program extract a particular row value as mentioned in question

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17467542/python-xlrd-module

Comment: Thanks Nikko and Archarya. This information gives me a clear indication. thank you !